How do office poster laws affect businesses with no office?
US labor laws require businesses to post various posters in their offices, informing employees of various matters regarding employment law.  But over the past several years, we've seen the rise of "remote-first" businesses that do not have an office; all employees simply work from home.
These employees still have the same rights under employment law, of course, and presumably the same right to be informed of those rights.  How is this handled, under the law and/or any applicable case law?

It's of course extremely funny to think that someone would be competent enough to work from home but not competent enough to Google what their rights are. Doubly so given that US employers can terminate anyone on the spot with no cause, so the list of "rights" on these posters is quite laughable.

@JonathanReez "employers can terminate anyone on the spot with no cause" Ironically, if you had a poster, you'd know that you can't be fired for having a child, having a serious health issue, having to take care of a child because your spouse was militarily deployed, etc.

@user71659 I've checked and none of the mandatory posters talk about that specific rule, at least in the Federal or NY state posters.

@JonathanReez You didn't check hard enough.

@user71659 that poster doesn't talk about whether you can be fired for having a child, only that you must be allowed to take the FMLA. The actual law protecting this right is the Pregnancy Discrimination Act of 1978 and its not mentioned at all.

One of the more silly versions of this is the H-1B notification law (https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/fact-sheets/62m-h1b-notice), where the Employer is supposed to notify all employees at the workplace, so that American employees can check they aren't being replaced. For the case of a remote worker converting from another visa to H-1B, the only person at their 'workplace' is themselves.

@user1937198 they've revised the rules in 2019 and electronic posting is now allowed.

@JonathanReez That doesn't change that the only person you electronically post it to is the one person that the notice isn't really relevant to, and the rule about notifying all remote workers doesn't seem to apply for a hybrid org.

@user1937198 I think that requirement is only relevant if you're doing electronic posting as a wholesale replacement for real posters. If you're hybrid you presumably have to use physical posters for the in-office workers, and can add an electronic version for remotes.

@Barmar for the general posters that is applicable. For the H-1B notifications, because its only relevant to a specific 'worksite' theirs cases of defining a 'worksite' as only the single remote worker, and not the onsite workers, and so not actually notifying anyone.

@user71659 irrelevant. When a company (anywhere) wants to get rid of you they will find an excuse, however seemingly silly and irrelevant, that will stand legal scrutiny. If the HR and legal departments are halfway competent that is, which most tend to be in larger companies at the very least. So you're suffering from a burnout and can't be fired for being sick? No problem, we're firing you the day you come back to work for not meeting your targets (yes, I've had that happen, exactly like that).

@jwenting Yeah, sounds completely reasonable because employment law lawyers don't exist and there's rarely any wrongful termination lawsuits...

@user71659 most of which lawsuits end up as a win for the company. Certainly here they do, and even if not the settlements here are so low that the company gets rid of someone relatively cheap.

In the US, most employees are "at will", which means the company can fire for any reason other than discrimination of specific classes (and the poster should enumerate those classes). If you're in a union the contract may add additional restrictions, but they're probably not hard to get around as you say. @jwenting

The page you linked to says that the notices must be

provided to employees and/or posted in the workplace

When there's no workplace, I think this means you must provide the notice to employees in some other manner, such as email.
In particular, the OSH Act of 1970 contains the following language:

posting of notices or other appropriate means, keep their employees informed of their protections and obligations

Email and snail mail would fall under "other appropriate means".

Looking at some text of the laws, such as the OSH Act of 1970, the phrasing there is The Secretary shall also issue regulations requiring that employers, through posting of notices or other appropriate means, keep their employees informed of their protections and obligations under this Act. Without reading every statute and regulation listed, I would expect that most have similar terminology involving "other appropriate means".

Thanks. I was trying to find something like that by following links from the above page.

In December 2020, the U.S. Department of Labor published bulletin #2020-7 on the topic of Electronic posting of notices. It is not marked as withdrawn by the DoL as of 2024, so it remains valid.
Compliance rules for remote employers
Regulations mandating workplace posters were introduced as early as 1939, so the original texts are typically silent on the possibility of remote work. The Wage and Hour Division of the DoL, responsible for enforcing various poster laws, provides the following guidance for remote employers:

If a statute and its regulations require a notice to be continuously posted at a worksite, in most cases, WHD will only consider electronic posting an acceptable substitute for the continuous posting requirement where:
(1) All of the employer’s employees exclusively work remotely,
(2) All employees customarily receive information from the employer via electronic means, and
(3) All employees have readily available access to the electronic posting at all times.

Procedures for specific laws

Fair Labor Standards Act, Family and Medical Leave Act, Employee Polygraph Protection Act:


In this circumstance, where there is no physical establishment where employees are employed and employees can access the electronic posting at any time, WHD will consider such electronic posting to meet the regulatory requirements that the notice be posted in a conspicuous place where employees are employed so as to permit them to readily observe a copy.


Section 14(c) of the Fair Labor Standards Act


Where the employer finds it inappropriate to post such a notice, the regulations permit an employer to satisfy this requirement by providing the poster directly to all employees subject to its terms. Therefore, if an employer finds it inappropriate to post a physical notice to employees, an employer may satisfy the Section 14(c) posting requirements in 29 C.F.R. § 525.14 by emailing or direct mailing the poster to workers employed under 14(c) subminimum wage certificates or, where appropriate, the parents and/or guardians of such employees.


Service Contract Act


Where, as described above,
(1) All of the employer’s employees exclusively work remotely,
(2) All employees customarily receive information from the employer via electronic means, and
(3) All employees have readily available access to the electronic posting at all times,
WHD would consider this worksite posting requirement to be met if an electronic posting of WH Publication 1313, and the applicable wage determination, is as readily accessible to those workers as a hard-copy posting would be.

Each jurisdiction will have additional rules
All 50 states, as well as some counties and cities, have their own mandatory workplace posters as well. One example of how compliance is done can be found on Washington State University's website where a public page for employees combines federal, Washington, and Seattle posters in one place.
Another company went even further and just combined posters from every single state into one giant PDF, which is presumably sufficient to ensure country-wide compliance if this document is easy for their employees to find.

2020, the year the pandemic started. Probably not a coincidence.

@Barmar remote-only companies existed for at least two decades now, I'm sure they somehow made it work back then too :-)

I know -- I've been working for one for 13 years. But during the pandemic suddenly the vast majority were remote-only, so it became important to revise the regulations clearly.
